# Eclipse-lib issue of web project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, myeclipse

I used to myeclipse before,recently I use Eclipse,and I like lib sorting in web-inf .but now when i do it ,the background say can't find jar package. i check the webapps Directory in tomcat,it's the same as myeclipse do.and my tomcat is 7.0.

why this happen?thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the jar in Build Path.even though you have copied into WEB-INF you need to add the reference using
`Right Click Project in eclipse-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries` tab and add external jars and make the references to the required jars.

Comment: well i can't find class why?